# Replace only specified occurrences of string - Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am playing around with re module in python, what i am stuck at is I want to replace only specified occurrences of the string.
**for example**

```py
import re
string = "aabbaabbaabbabbaabbaa"
#I want to replace only 3rd time 'bb' appeared in the string with white space
string = re.sub("bb"," ",string,3)   #if iI do this all first 3 occurrences got replaced
print(string)
```

**output**

```
aa aa aa aabbaabbaa
```

any idea how to to replace only 3rd occurrence
so the output would look like **This**

```
aabbaabbaa aabbaabbaa
```

Comment: You could match it 2 times and capture it in a group. Then match the 3rd time to be replaced. `^((?:[^b]+bb){2}[^b]*)bb` https://regex101.com/r/IDy9qT/1 This assumes that where are no occurrences of a single `b` in between. https://ideone.com/TYTOGC

Comment: ahh, yes we can do that but I am wondering isn't there any in built methods in re to do that, cause the string above was just an example.

Comment: @Thefourthbird doesn't this will replace more than one that fit into the pattern

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat It replaces the third occurrence after matching any char except b using `[^b]+` That by itself is a broad match, if there are only a's it can be `a+` like `^((?:a+bb){2}a+)bb` https://regex101.com/r/EfBW5Q/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the regex so it only matches the third occurrence?

```
re.sub(r'(.*?bb.*?bb.*?)bb', r'\1 ', string, 1)
```

This could be extended to a large number of repetitions like `r'(.*?(bb.*?){9999})bb'`

Comment: what would be the regex if i want to replace only 10000th "bb" in a different string?

Comment: `r'(.*?(bb.*?){9999})bb'`

Comment: Nice, but wouldn't this be problematic when 'bbbbb' would occur in string?

Comment: @JvdV "Problematic" how? The first two pairs are a match each, and the remaining lone `b` is not part of a match.

Comment: I guess its problematic as soon as bbbb is considered a different substring too bb. If not, thats great. BB is probably simplified as well. So what if the substring would be 'America' and part of a larger substring 'American'. Different words and shouldn't be counted. Hopefully it's clear?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the perfect way but it is a solution:

```
string = re.sub('bb',' ',string, 3)
string = re.sub(' ','bb',string,2)
```

This is just an alternative solution I can think of.

Comment: what if there is a `bbbbaabbbbabbb`

Comment: haha it's a clever solution but I think the time complexity would be doubled by this

Comment: @JvdV yes that would be an complication,it would be better to find  a regex for such question

Comment: @sarthakChaudhary yes it will,I am thinking this solution is more of a method when you don't  want to invest more time on writing a regular exp for not a very complex problems like yourself

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat The above string was just an example,What if the string is very large and we only want to replace some occurrences, I think re.sub should have start, stop and step arguments.

Comment: in that case,you should always go for a regex pattern